# Scrollbars behaving badly in auto-sizing boxes on IE7, FF and Chrome

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

If anyone has a better idea for a title, I'm all ears.

Here's a JSFiddle that demonstrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/VXsAg/

In a nutshell, I have an element with fixed height and stretch-to-contents width. If the contents are higher than the fixed height, there should be a vertical scrollbar. There should also be ONLY vertical scrollbar, because horizontally it can stretch as much as is needed anyway. Unfortunately I cannot get it to work in a cross-browser compatible way. Here's what I get (the top box is for reference, the bottom box demonstrates the problem):

In IE8, IE9 and Opera 11.60 it appears like this (very good):

[image: Good]

In IE7, Chrome 17 and Firefoxes 3 & 10 it appears like this (disaster):

[image: Bad]

I can see why it happens (width is calculated before scrollbars are taken into account), but how can I work around it?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently nobody knows. Well, I solved it via javascript. Basically I did the autosizing part myself. I calculated the size of the contents; calculated the size of the scrollbar; and set the width explicitly.